# React Redux Form set initial value from store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form, redux-thunk

I have a form, posted below with much of it cut out for simplicity's sake, that I need to initialize with values from the redux store.

I already mapped the props from the redux store to the component, (in props.initialValues), but it won't set the initial state of the form.

Also when I try to type in the text boxes of the form, it won't let me type anything.

I'm using the form elements from `@material-ui/core`.  To see the full code without any cuts, you can view it [here](https://bitbucket.org/cclloyd9785/opensrd-fullstack/src/master/frontend/src/components/layout/FormSpellEdit.js).

How can I initialize the values in the form?

```
class FormSpellEdit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            Name: 'NoName',
            School: 'NoSchool',
            Subschool: 'NoSubschool',
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;

        const renderTextField = ({
            input,
            label,
            ...custom
        }) => (
            <TextField
                hintText={label}
                label={label}
                floatingLabelText={label}
                {...input}
                {...custom}
            />
        );

        return (
            <form
                onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                initialValues={this.props.page.spell}
                >

                <Grid fluid>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={4} >
                            <Field
                                fullWidth
                                initialValue={this.state.Name}
                                name="Name"
                                component={renderTextField}
                                label="Spell Name"
                            />
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={4} >
                            <Field
                                fullWidth
                                name="School"
                                component={renderTextField}
                                label="Spell School"
                            />
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={4} >
                            <Field
                                fullWidth
                                name="Subschool"
                                component={renderTextField}
                                label="Spell Subschool"
                            />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>

            </form>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
        user_id: userId(state),
        initialValues: state.spell,
        formValues: getFormValues(props.form)(state),
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
    }
};


export default compose(
    reduxForm({
        form: 'SpellEditForm',
    }),
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps,

    ),
    withStyles(styles, {
            withTheme: true
        },
    ))(FormSpellEdit);
```

Answer (score 0):

try add connected component **before** `reduxForm`, names **must** match

```
export default compose(
        connect(
            mapStateToProps,
            mapDispatchToProps,

        ),
        reduxForm({
            form: 'SpellEditForm',
        }),

        withStyles(styles, {
                withTheme: true
            },
        ))(FormSpellEdit);
```

Comment: The names do match up with both the state key names and the form `Name` name.  I tried moving the connect to be first and nothing changed.

Comment: than try wrapped components: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui, branch 0.5

Comment: that hasn't been updated to material-ui 1.0 release yet.

Comment: thats true, but its working very well with material-ui 1.0, we use in some projects

Comment: yea but when I try that I get an error

> ./node_modules/redux-form-material-ui/lib/AutoComplete.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/AutoComplete' in '/app/frontend/node_modules/redux-form-material-ui/lib'